# uploading an image to S3 via javascript AWS sdk results in '[object object]' string

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ionic3, aws-sdk

By following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@bevin.hernandez/angular-5-file-uploads-to-s3-with-relative-ease-ea19b7fd120e), I'm trying to upload an image from my ionic application to an amazon s3 bucket using the following code:

```
uploadFile(filePath) {
    console.log('uploading: ', filePath);
    this.getFile(filePath).subscribe((file) => {
       console.log('file is', file);

       this.s3.upload({
          Key: file.name,
          Bucket: this.bucketName,
          Body: file,
          ACL: 'public-read'
        }, (err, data) => {
           console.log('error', err);
           console.log('data', data);
     })
   });
}

getFile(filePath):Observable<any> {
  return Observable.create((obs) => {
    (<any>window).resolveLocalFileSystemURL(filePath,(fileEntry) => {
      fileEntry.file((fileObject) => {
        obs.next(fileObject);
      })
    })
  });
}
```

This connects to aws fine, but the file it uploads is just a text file with `[object object]` in it instead of the jpeg image data. for context the `filePath` argument is being passed a filepath to an image that is being generated via the Ionic 3 `@ionic-native/camera` library and I'm running the code via the android emulator, if that makes any difference.

I'm pretty sure I'm passing the wrong type of object to the `Body` property when I'm doing the upload, but I can't figure out what it should be. The AWS documentation says it should accept the type of `Blob`, but my `getFile` method returns a `File` which is apparently an instance of `Blob`, so I figured it should work fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `GetFile` method returns a `File` object and not a blob.
So when, you write :

```
Body: file,
```

you're actually passing that JS object, not a blob.
The proof this is an object is that `file.name` does actually return a name.

I would suggest you to look at the doc of `fileEntry.file` to check how you can access the byte array from the `File` object returned.

From Cordova [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/1.8.0/cordova/file/fileentry/fileentry.html) :

`file: Creates a File object containing file properties.`

Maybe the `FileReader` will hep you to actually read the file.
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/1.8.1/cordova/file/filereader/filereader.html

Comment: You were right! I used `FileReader` to read the file as an array buffer, and passing that to `Body` seemed to work. It's weird though, because the aws sdk docs say that `Body` should accept `Blob`, of which `File` is an instance of. I would have thought that `File` should work too.